# How to check that float property of managed object is nil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Score is NSManagedObject. score.latitude is an NSNumber, which actually is a float value.

```
NSLog(@"%f", [score.latitude floatValue]);
```

shows **0.000000**.

Construction I use to check for nil:

if (score.latitude == nil)

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's irrelevant that there is a floating-point value stored in your `NSNumber` instance; the object itself is either `nil` or not. To check for an object being `nil`, `if( obj == nil )` is functionally equivalent to `if( obj )`.

So your conditional may not be doing what you expect, but it *is* checking for `nil`. You'd need to add more details about what's happening in the body of the `if`, should you need more specific explanation.

The key point is that sending a message to `nil`, such as `[nil floatValue]` always returns `0`, interpreted as whatever the return type of the method is. For example, if you send `floatValue` to `nil`, you'll get back floating-point 0. If you send a message that should return an object, you'll get `nil`; a message that should return an `int`, you get integer 0.

Also be aware that when you say `if( score.latitude )`, the expression will evaluate false if *either* `score` or `latitude` is `nil` (because if `score` is `nil`, sending `latitude` to it will return `nil`.)

Answer (score 0):

A float can be nil, as it isn't an object.

And a NSNumber is not an float value, but has a method, that returns a float value.

use `if (score)` to check, if the NSNumber got instantiated before.

Answer (score 0):

As I finally understand, the problem is because of Core Data save data to sql database, which stores nil properties as 0.000...